# Missing top element in VStack when run on target

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a simple view containing a `VStack` with one line of text containing the titles of a list (think header) followed by a `List`.

```
struct CampaignView : View {
  let campaign: Campaign

  init(from campaign: Campaign) {
    self.campaign = campaign
  }

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ObservationRow.titles
        .padding([.top, .leading], 8)
      List(campaign.observations) {
        ObservationRow(from: $0)
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

On the simulator, everything looks good but when I run it on my target (macOS) my titles row is missing. NOTE: The content of the preview and target app are different. It is the top line that is missing.
[image]

When I added three arbitrary Text fields above the title, The top most element is again missing and the titles are now shown because they are further down the stack.
[image]

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("A")
      Text("B")
      Text("C")
      ObservationRow.titles
        .padding([.top, .leading], 8)
      List(campaign.observations) {
        ObservationRow(from: $0)
      }
    }
  }
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Does it bother you that your screenshots contain different iterations of your `List()? Be it Date (Timestamp?) or Distance I'd think that I'd post screenshots where the actual cells matched. just trying to help - this could be related to the actual issue. (This applies to both before/after you added your arbitrary rows in the header.)

Comment: in both cases, the List is displayed in its entirety - correctly. In the first case a special ObservationRowView (HStack of Text) is missing. In the other just a plain Text is missing. So I am not sure how this relates to the List or its values. As far as why the data difference, one is hard coded in my `#if DEBUG` for the simulator. The other data is from a JSON file in the application support directory running in my Mac app.

Comment: It looks like `A` hides behind the top bar. it would be great if you post missing data types so anyone can reproduce the situation and try to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `.fullSizeContentView` from your window setup in AppDelegate.swift so it looks like this:

```
window = NSWindow(
    contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
    styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable],
    backing: .buffered, defer: false)
```

Now your content view will show all!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the SwiftUI framework and has been reported to Apple. The simplest method to recreate this issue is to start with a clean, SwiftUI based, macOS project. Modify the provided ContentView with this body.

```
var body: some View {
  VStack {
    Text("A")
    List(1...4) {
      Text("\($0)")
    }
  }
}
```

The Xcode Preview will be displayed correctly but when the new app is run on a Mac, the "A" Text element is missing behind the title bar of the window. We know it is being clipped by the title bar because SwiftUI adds (on its own) a grey background to the `Text("A")` of which only a couple of lines are still visible.

A workaround for now is to simply prepend a `Text(" ")` element to the VStack so that it is clipped but allows the rest of the stack to be displayed.

Comment: Xcode 11.0 beta 2 (11M337n) was released today and crashed on the `Text("A")` initialization call. Neither the Preview nor target app will run.